# Change the Selected TEXT Color on Spark DataGrid cell

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

Does anyone know a way to apply style on selected text in a Spark DataGrid?

I think that the best way is to have an itemrenderer with textarea but after, I don't know how to do.

My goal isn't to change color label if cell is selected. 
Indeed, in my dream, item is editable, and you can selected only some words inside cell and apply a specific style to the selected part of text (by click on a button, one for bold, one for italic...). Than, text may be store in database like html text.

I'd like use cell itemrenderer like a RichTextEditor but without ControlBar. In my case, I'd like to have only one control bar outside the datadgrid.

I'll happy, if you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Best approach with Spark is generally a skin.

There's rudimentary control via properties, such as changing the selected color:

[image: cell]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:DataGrid selectionColor="0xff0000">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>a</fx:String>
                <fx:String>b</fx:String>
                <fx:String>c</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:DataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

To implement an item renderer for a GridColumn, use `States` to define how the selected state will appear

[image: cell-renderer]

**GridColumnItemRenderer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void
            {
                lblData.text = data[column.dataField]
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="lblData"
             color.selected="0x00ff00"
             top="9"
             left="7" />

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

**DataGrid**

Item renderer above is specified from a Spark GridColumn, as in:

```
<s:DataGrid>
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn itemRenderer="GridColumnItemRenderer" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I thinks my explain is bad because my goal isn't to change color label if cell is selected. Indeed, in my dream, item is editable, and you can selected only some words inside cell and apply a specific style to the selected part of text. Than, text may be store in database like html text.

Comment: Your edited question is essentially a new question, 100% different than what you originally asked.